# Exporting Spring MBeans to Tomcat's MBeanServer Instance

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, jmx

I am playing around with spring's JMX support with a WAR file I deploy on a tomcat server (which I have running locally).  However, despite following the posted guides, I am unable to deploy my MBeans specifically to tomcat's MBeanServer instance.

I have tried a few variations of MBeanExporter and MBeanServerFactoryBean configurations, and nothing seems to be working.  Here is my current configuration:

```
<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:6969/jmxrmi"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer"/>
    <property name="beans">
        <map>
            <entry key="domain:name=notifier" value-ref="mBeanNotifier"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mBeanNotifier" class="com.sei.poc.jmx.mbeans.SimpleMBeanNotifier"/>
```

And I have included the following arguments in tomcat's configuration as well:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6969
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

I am able to connect to the mbeanServer manually by entering localhost:6969 into JConsole, but I only find native catalina MBeans.  When I dig through those MBeans, I even find references to my project, but unfortunately the MBean I declare is nowhere to be found.

I have tried removing the MBeanServerFactoryBean declaration in the hope that the exporter would be able to pick up tomcat's MBeanServer nativly (with no luck).  I have tried different variations of the service url as well, without success.

I should note that I am able to deploy MBeans to my local MBeanServer and view them with JConsole just fine.

Any suggestions as to what the problem could be would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this helps/I explained it clearly, but I have never had an issue when I am running a test in a jar file and deploying MBeans to the local MBeanServer (which from what I read I believe is the PlatformMBeanServer).  Only when I put a test in a war, deploy it to tomcat, and connect to tomcat's MBeanServer (and at this point, I can only assume I am actually establishing that connection) that I am unable to see my MBeans with JConsole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue.  I am writing this test as a Spring MVC application, and thus have a few levels of context, broken up into different context files.

The issue was simply that the context file that held the MBeanExporter and MBean declarations were not being initialized until I actually went to localhost:/, which prompted the servlet to start loading its context files.

After connecting with my browser, the MBeans appeared in JConsole.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a ServiceURL to get an MBeanServerConnection, the returned object is not an MBeanServer (i.e. it does not support registerObject).

Try replacing your mbeanServer bean with:

```
<bean id="mbeanServer" class="java.lang.management.ManagementFactory"
    lazy-init="false" factory-method="getPlatformMBeanServer">
</bean>
```

This will provide you a direct reference to the platform MBeanServer, which is what your JConsole is connecting to.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Nicholas.  I tried your suggestion and I still can't see my MBean in JConsole.  I checked each MBean server that JConsole detected and I even retried localhost:6969.  Tried removing the vm-args as well and still no luck.